# Getting a "Headers already sent" error in Yii when rendering a view in beforeAction

Tags: yii, yii2

I've read about Yii2's handlers and I don't grasp how to use them properly for this case.

Basically in my `SiteController`, I have:

```
class SiteController extends \app\components\Controller
{
    public function beforeAction($action)
    {
        // Makes some checks and if it's true, will render a file and stop execution of any action
        if (...)
            echo $this->render('standby');
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    // All my other actions here
}
```

This seems to work well and stop the execution, however I get the "Headers already sent" for the `render()` line, as if it was doing a redirection.

If I write `Yii::$app-end()` instead of `return false`, same thing happens.

If I write `exit();` instead of `return false`, no exception shows but the debug panel doesn't show since Yii doesn't terminate correctly.

I tried removing echo `$this->render(..)` and it results in an empty page, no redirection whatsoever, this seems like it's only Yii complaining that I echo stuff from the Controller.

And of course I can't return the result of `render()` or return `true`, since it will execute the page's action, which I'm trying to avoid and end here.

I know returning false in `beforeAction()` triggers `EVENT_BEFORE_ACTION` but I don't see where I'm supposed to use that. The [events documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/concept-events) didn't really help me.

So is there a way to display the "standby" view, preventing other actions from executing and avoid the error message for echoing from the `Controller`?

Please note that I'm trying to make this work without having to duplicate code in each action method to check if the result of `beforeAction()` was false.

Comment: is there a reason you're not just using a redirect?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since Yii 2.0.14 you cannot echo in controller - response must be returned by action. If you want to generate response in `beforeAction()` you need to setup `Yii::$app->response` component instead of echoing content:

```
public function beforeAction($action) {
    // Makes some checks and if it's true, will render a file and stop execution of any action
    if (...) {
        Yii::$app->response->content = $this->render('standby');
        Yii::$app->response->statusCode = 403; // use real HTTP status code here

        return false;
    }

    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

Don't forget to call `parent::beforeAction($action)` - omitting  it will result unexpected and hard to debug behavior.

Comment: Straight to the point, easy, clean, well-explained. Thank you sir, wish I could upvote 2 times! And extra thanks for flagging my error about not calling the parent method

Comment: exactly, yii 2 does not allow normally to send raw output inside controller actions like render output, since it is afterwards trying to send headers about the response type, but just after. And php usually complains about the first occurrence of the output in this case, but it does not  says much about whether and where are "headers" function called after in Yii