# yii2 Prevent action from being executed conditionally

Tags: php, controller, yii2

I have a `MyController` that extends `\yii\web\Controller` and is extended by every controller. On the `MyController`, I overwrite the parent's `beforeAction()` wherein I do already some stuff.

Now I want to implement a disclaimer which should disappear only when the user clicks on the "I agree" button.

Until the user did not did that, he can't use any menu of the site.

My suggestion was to check the state if the disclaimer was confirmed once already or not in the `beforeAction()` method of `MyController` and if it was not confirmed to render the disclaimer and prevent executing the requested action.

This did not work because I could not figure out how to prevent the action from being executed.

Does someone knows another solution or can tell me how to prevent the action from being executed?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50355074/5812455)

Comment: It works! Thank you very much! How can I honor you?

Comment: You can upvote linked answer and question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting a "Headers already sent" error in Yii when rendering a view in beforeAction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50354629/getting-a-headers-already-sent-error-in-yii-when-rendering-a-view-in-beforeact)